# Keyboard appearing in mobile

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am using bootstrap 3 to develop mobile application. In android devices keyboard is appearing on drop downs. Any idea how to stop this in mobile?

Comment: what are you using to create the dropdown?

Comment: Can you post the related code?

Comment: Also post which android version you are talking about..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: how will that affect if he needs input? also he never mentioned if he is doing in Java.. far i can see it looks like he is just doing a website and calling it web application